# await in Meteor / React project doesn't work

Tags: meteor, async-await

I'm trying to use 'await' in an async function so as to avoid callbacks. There is no error, but the line of code after the method call executes immediately and the return value from the method isn't picked up.

I'm using React but I don't think that should affect this code. I assume the async and await commands are provided by babel-runtime so I shouldn't need to include anything else manually? I have read many examples and tutorials, and have tried lots of variations, with no success. I must be missing something really basic but I can't figure it out.

Server:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'asyncTest': function() {
        setTimeout(() => {return 'cheese';}, 2000);
    }
});
```

Client:

```
Meteor.myFunctions = {
    'test': async function Test() {
        let result1 = await (Meteor.call('asyncTest'));
        console.log(`got result ${result1}`);
    },
};
```

When I run `Meteor.myFunctions.test()` in the browser console, I see the following output immediately:

```
Promise { "pending" }
<state>: "pending"
__proto__: PromiseProto { done: common.js/exports.Promise.prototype.done(), … }
got result undefined
```

There is no error, but it's clearly not working; there ought to be a two second delay and it should say "got result cheese".

I have also tried this server code:

```
import { Promise } from 'meteor/promise';

Meteor.methods({
'asyncTest': function() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {console.log('cheese'); resolve('cheese');}, 2000);
        });
    },
});
```

This also doesn't work.

Any help gratefully received.

versions:

METEOR@1.6.0.1

babel-runtime@^6.26.0

react@16.2.0

EDIT 2: I got @Tolsee's suggestion working :) Among other things I made a dumb mistake in my test method, using setTimeout to delay return. Of course this didn't work because the function called at the end of the timeout isn't the method. This code works for me:

Server:

```
Meteor.methods({
'asyncTest': function() {
        var timeNow = new Date();
        while (new Date().getSeconds() < timeNow.getSeconds() + 3) {
        }
        return 'cheese';
    },
});
```

Client:

```
success = function(res) {
    console.log('result ' + res);
}

failure = function(err) {
    console.log('failure ' + err);
}

promisedCall = function(method) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Meteor.call(method, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(res);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Run this code in the console: `promisedCall('asyncTest').then(success, failure);`

As expected there is a 3 second delay, then `result cheese` appears in the console.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, [`async-await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) is provided by javascript, not babel.

In `async` function, you can have `await` which pauses the function until the `Promise` is resolved. So, `await` cannot be used with `Meteor.call`, which does not return the `Promise`.

Now, let's take a look  your code:

**First Client Code:**

```
Meteor.myFunctions = {
    'test': async function Test() {
        let result1 = await (Meteor.call('asyncTest')); // Bucause Meteor.call does not return promise.
        console.log(`got result ${result1}`);
     },
};
```

I don't know what you are trying to do in the second example. If you are thinking that when you return promise in the method, then the client will get the `Promise`, It's wrong thinking. The promise is resolved in the server and data is passed back to the client, so It doesn't make any difference from client's perspective.

You wanna use this library: https://github.com/deanius/meteor-promise

EDIT:
You can create a simple promised method call function yourself.

```
function promisedCall(method) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Meteor.call(method, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      } else {
        resolve(res)
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: deanius promise seems not to be maintained, the last update was 2 years ago. I don't think I should depend on that in my app.

Comment: So - all the posts that talk about using async to avoid callback hell - are they only talking about server code? i.e. calling one server from another? Does it not apply for calling server methods from the client?

Comment: @LittleBrain Please check my edit to find how you can create a promised method call.

Comment: I have got it working now and thank you for your answer.